# Loop returning Null value when using $ operator

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

***Background***:
I am applying the slope and offset from my standard curve to my raw data. The raw data is organized in a data frame with "Group" on the Y axis and Time points on the X axis. Each group, A through F, has 12 rows and its own standard curve. The standard curve values are in a separate data frame.

***Issue***: I tried to write a loop ( `for (char in abc)`...) to go through each group and create a final data frame with all the raw data transformed but Im having an issue using the `$` operator and the iterable variable (not sure what its called)  i.e. `stdcrv.data$char`, this is the SLOPE step in the below code. I get a NULL value for `SLOPE` and  `stdcrv.data$char`.

Can the `$` opperator not be used with `char`? How should I fix this loop? I attached the 'Working Code' which runs and does what I need, I made one for each letter but I would rather have it running as a loop than six of those.

***Loop Summary***: The loop should go through each letter and subset the 12 rows of raw data per letter. Then it should create a variable of the unique slope and the unique offset from the stdcrv.data. The final line transforms the raw data by those variables and binds them to a new data frame. This is what is done in the working code, it just doesn't loop.

*Still new to SO if Im putting too much info in my question let me know, thanks*

raw.data:

```
Group 11:29  11:43  11:56  12:10  12:23   12:38   12:53   13:07   13:21   13:37   14:07   14:38   15:13
1     A 36090 123346 280239 529487 898173 1370663 1906590 2396293 2984783 3811666 5325242 6771652 8599776
2     A 33316 103971 245647 480937 826774 1256875 1680066 2174810 2621266 3327056 4733830 6035170 7601268
```

stdcrv.data:

```
 X            A            B            C            D            E            F
1  Slope 1.190980e+05 1.178085e+05 112511.14940 1.097752e+05 1.136168e+05 1.036628e+05
2 Offset 1.859640e+05 1.588433e+05  59179.53093 1.343089e+05 1.369816e+05 9.994541e+03
```

Working Code

```
A<-raw.data[grep("A",raw.data$Group),]
Asub<-A[2:15]
ASLOPE<-stdcrv.data$A[grep("Slope",stdcrv.data$X)]
AOFFSET<-stdcrv.data$A[grep("Offset",stdcrv.data$X)]
Final<- cbind(A[1],(Asub-AOFFSET)/ASLOPE)

B<-raw.data[grep("B",raw.data$Group),]
Bsub<-B[2:15]
BSLOPE<-stdcrv.data$B[grep("Slope",stdcrv.data$X)]
BOFFSET<-stdcrv.data$B[grep("Offset",stdcrv.data$X)]
Final<- rbind(Final,(cbind(B[1],(Bsub-BOFFSET)/BSLOPE)))
```

Attempt at Loop:

```
abc<- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F')
for (char in abc){
  char.df <- raw.data[grep(char,raw.data$Group),]
  char.df.subset<-char.df[2:15]
  SLOPE<-stdcrv.data$char[grep("Slope",stdcrv.data$X)]
}
```

Comment: Instead of `stdcrv.data$char` you should use `stdcrv.data[[char]]`.

Comment: Yes thank you! I got the loop running now. Could you explain why that doesn't work and the double brackets?

Comment: `stdcrv.data$char` litterally means to look for the `char` column/variable. It does not mean to grab the variable that matches what is in `char`.